# Is xxhash a one-way hash?

Tags: hash

Is [xxhash](http://cyan4973.github.io/xxHash) a one-way hash algorithm?

The documentation does not state this.

Comment: However, the documentation mentions that it's not suitable for use in cryptography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, documentation on xxhash seems hard to find. It does state pretty clearly that it's "for non-cryptographic use", so it probably depends what you mean by "one-way".

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash/blob/v0.6.2/xxhash.c), the magic seems to happen here (line 247, and line 278):

```
/* *******************************************************************
*  32-bits hash functions
*********************************************************************/
static const U32 PRIME32_1 = 2654435761U;
static const U32 PRIME32_2 = 2246822519U;
static const U32 PRIME32_3 = 3266489917U;
static const U32 PRIME32_4 =  668265263U;
static const U32 PRIME32_5 =  374761393U;

static U32 XXH32_round(U32 seed, U32 input)
{
    seed += input * PRIME32_2;
    seed  = XXH_rotl32(seed, 13);
    seed *= PRIME32_1;
    return seed;
}

...

if (len>=16) {
    const BYTE* const limit = bEnd - 16;
    U32 v1 = seed + PRIME32_1 + PRIME32_2;
    U32 v2 = seed + PRIME32_2;
    U32 v3 = seed + 0;
    U32 v4 = seed - PRIME32_1;

    do {
            v1 = XXH32_round(v1, XXH_get32bits(p)); p+=4;
            v2 = XXH32_round(v2, XXH_get32bits(p)); p+=4;
            v3 = XXH32_round(v3, XXH_get32bits(p)); p+=4;
            v4 = XXH32_round(v4, XXH_get32bits(p)); p+=4;
        } while (p<=limit);

        h32 = XXH_rotl32(v1, 1) + XXH_rotl32(v2, 7) + XXH_rotl32(v3, 12) + XXH_rotl32(v4, 18);
    } else {
        h32  = seed + PRIME32_5;
    }

    h32 += (U32) len;

    while (p+4<=bEnd) {
        h32 += XXH_get32bits(p) * PRIME32_3;
        h32  = XXH_rotl32(h32, 17) * PRIME32_4 ;
        p+=4;
    }

    while (p<bEnd) {
        h32 += (*p) * PRIME32_5;
        h32 = XXH_rotl32(h32, 11) * PRIME32_1 ;
        p++;
    }

    h32 ^= h32 >> 15;
    h32 *= PRIME32_2;
    h32 ^= h32 >> 13;
    h32 *= PRIME32_3;
    h32 ^= h32 >> 16;

    return h32;
```

"One-way" in cryptography means that it's computationally infeasible to reverse it or generate collisions. Since this is some bit-shifting plus a bunch of additions, multiplications, and exponentiations with fixes primes and a fixed modulus (32-bytes). You could probably come up with a Chinese Remainder Theorem based algorithm to break it. So as the documentation says, it's certainly not "one-way" in the cryptographic sense of the word.

Note that there are other definitions of "one-way" that make sense in a non-cryptographic sense. For example the hash function of taking a person's initials is "one-way" in the sense that `JS` could equally be `Jon Snow`, `Jane Smith`, `Johann Sebastian`, etc.